# Shindig - Could not fetch gadget spec (security tokens?)

Tags: security, oauth, widget, apache-shindig

I'm working with shindig trying to get some OAuth1 gadgets working outside any container (using the gadgets/ifr thing).

I've been using the 'gadget testing container' and everything works just fine, which means every key is setted correctly on the oauth.json.

The problem begins when I try to display those same gadgets outside the container. I get this error:

```
OAuth error: UNKNOWN_PROBLEM: Could not fetch gadget spec
==== 
Original request: 
GET stuff.json 
Host: my.host 
X-Shindig-AuthType: oauth 
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1 
X-shindig-dos: on
====
```

The url I use is something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/gadgets/ifr?url=http://my.host/stuff.xml
```

I thing the problem here has some relation with the &st parameter (security token)...

For the record, if I use some already provided gagdet by shindig it works without any problems (those are OAuth2.0 though):

```
http://localhost:8080/gadgets/ifr?url=http://localhost:8080/samplecontainer/examples/oauth2/oauth2_facebook.xml
```

I've been searching this question and lots of people have this same problem but no answers. 
I think this could be the place they're looking for :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who has my same problem, this is how I managed to fix it.

As you can see I was trying to render the widget through the basic ifr url. That's not how shindig works. It needs some javascript to render the content you need.

What did I do?
I simply created a custom 'container', it receives an url param with the gadget xml's url and, through javascript, I render that gadget.

The javascript I'm using is the one wich comes in shindig (samplecontainer/samplecontainer.js) with basics modifications.

Hope this works... It's not easy though >.<
Grettings!!1one